# Phone light Turn On when incoming call come

Tags: android, android-hardware

I got incoming call and working well. But when my screen is turn off and an incoming call is come. Then my screen **light is not on**. I am using this code in onCreate():-

```
getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON
          | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
          );


    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    wl.acquire();
```

Also when my screen light ON and an incoming call come then my connection with server is successful. But when my screen light OFF and incoming call come(by service run in background for registration with server) then my **registration is failed** .

please android expert help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following in oncreate

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

and use the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" >
</uses-permission>
```

Comment: i will check. my networking is not working temporary! Thank u your answer is looking correct.

Comment: hi brother i need one more help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121514/sharedpreferences-is-lose-data-when-app-crashed-not-retreive-data-when-app-rebo