# App Crash Boot the Phone

Tags: android

I am totally confused as to why the app is crashing when I boot the phone.

My `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.callmenew"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi"  />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"  />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:icon="@drawable/appslogo"> 
     <service android:name=".MService"/>
     <activity android:name=".Login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".searchcall" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".SoftwarePassionView" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".outcall" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" android:label="Call Receiver" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.callmenew.MyBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" >  
<intent-filter>  
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>  
 </receiver>
    <activity android:name=".incomingcallevent" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".city" android:noHistory="true" android:label="City" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".createAd" android:label="Create Your Advertisement" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".rgtrUser1" android:label="Create Your Account" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
</application>
```

My `MyBroadcastreceiver`:

```
public class MyBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(arg0, searchcall.class);
        // startServiceIntent.putExtra("starts", "starts");
        // startServiceIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        // arg0.startActivity(startServiceIntent);
        Toast.makeText(arg0.getApplicationContext(), "start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

myservice class:-

```
 @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       Toast.makeText(this, "Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
       Log.i(tag, "Service created...");
   }

   @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Debug: SyncService onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("calldata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sipAddress = settings.getString("sipAddress", "");

      // sipAddress=  intent.getStringExtra("sipaddress");
      // sipcallid = intent.getStringExtra("sipAddress");

       Toast.makeText(MService.this, "sipAddress = "+sipAddress+" sipcallid ="+sipcallid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter();

        filter2.addAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        callReceiver2 = new IncomingCallReceiver();
        this.registerReceiver(callReceiver2, filter2);

         initializeManager(sipAddress);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Log cat:-

```
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     instantiate receiver com.callmenew.MyBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.callmenew.MyBroadcastReceiver
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2100)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.callmenew.MyBroadcastReceiver
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2095)
04-20 16:58:46.179: E/AndroidRuntime(294):  ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
</uses-permission>
```

Then declare the receiver like

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.callmenew.MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then in onReceive in code I am not sure whether you can show the toast directly there. If not you can start a service and from there show the toast. (in the last part I havent tried this , so someone correct me if wrong)

Comment: i m sry . again crash app. plz see my service class

Comment: instead of arg0.getApplicationContext() use arg0

Comment: thx m checking.. untill i m doing .  may u check my this query also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118721/phone-light-turn-on-when-incoming-call-come your help will be great full for me. thank u in advance

Comment: may it possible to restart my emulator?

Comment: you can turn off the emulator ... then instead of running from code start emulator from avd manager

Comment: again my app crash ! plz sir i m  confuse

Comment: thx working! U give me a correct way. please may you also check my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118721/phone-light-turn-on-when-incoming-call-come

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28556/discussion-between-stinepike-and-user2160008)

Comment: :) please check sir . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118721/phone-light-turn-on-when-incoming-call-come  This is my another bad issue